# How do I declare a source file's encoding in Rubinius?

Tags: ruby, rubinius

In MRI and JRuby I can do this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

This doesn't seem to work in rubinius.

Comment: Setting the default encoding with a comment at the top of the file works for me with rubinius-2.5.2. What version are you using and what code are you using to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @infused https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3370